# How can I get Linear Code Sequence And Jump (LCSAJ) Coverage?

Tags: code-coverage

How can I get Linear Code Sequence And Jump (LCSAJ) Coverage for my GCC C code?
(preferably GNU).

Info about the coverage: http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Linear_code_sequence_and_jump

Answer (score 1):

I could be wrong, but I believe LCSAJ was invented by LDRA (http://www.ldra.com/) .... and as such, the product that could get you there would be their LDRAcover
http://www.ldra.com/en/ldracover